# Different behavior of node.getElementsByClassName in different position

Tags: javascript

The statement `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("buttonQ")[0]);` placed in a specific position executes successfully, but the same statement when placed at another specific position executes undefined.

whats going on here ??

Statements in both positions are marked via comment in the code

```
    //quotes
    (function(){

      window.addEventListener("load", makeRequest);

      function makeRequest(){ 
        //-----the below statement "console.log" executes succesfully----
        console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("buttonQ")[0]); 
        document.getElementsByClassName("buttonQ")[0].addEventListener("click", makeRequest);
        function reqListener() {
          if(httpR.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var quote;
            if(httpR.status === 200) {
                quote = JSON.parse(httpR.responseText);
              document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].innerHTML = quote[0].body;
            } else {
              alert("There was a problem with the request!")
            }
          }
        }    
        var httpR;
        httpR = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpR.onreadystatechange = reqListener
        httpR.open("GET", "https://quote-api.glitch.me/pull/1", true);
        httpR.send();
      }

      //----------------------tweet-------------------

      //------the below statement "console.log" gives the result "undefined"----
      console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("buttonQ")[0]);


      //document.getElementsByClassName("buttonT")[0].addEventListener("click", tweetEvent);
      function tweetEvent() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].normalize();
        var tweetToShare = document.getElementsByClassName("quote")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        var urlForTweetButton = document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-share-button")[0].getAttribute("href");
        urlForTweetButton = urlForTweetButton + "?hashtags=quotes&text=" + encodeURIComponent(tweetToShare);
      }

    })();
```

Comment: first console.log runs after window loaded. second statement runs before window is loaded. that's why you are getting undefined

Comment: Your `makerequest` function is executed after page been loaded and DOM model is ready. Second statement even is placed below, but executed in early `readystate` phase, so element is not attached into DOM model. Or you can place script directly after `div` block, so it will be found - like root element in react renderer.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `MakeRequest` on document load, while the other statement is before the document has finished loading. Thus, at that moment, there probably isn't an element `.buttonQ` on the DOM yet.

Comment: yeah i got that. i have added my script tag in the head part.
shall i put my below statement inside the if statement with the condition `document.readyState === "complete"`. i did it but not working.

Comment: That won't work either, because at the moment of evaluation, the condition will not be fulfilled. You should use the different lifecycle events that the `window` object gives you. Here's some more info: https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded

Comment: yeah i think the optimal choice is window load event or document.onreadystatechange